# Calf Pain From Running

Tags: running, recovery

I should start by saying that I’m relatively new to running. I have dabbled in the past but I started semi-seriously about 6 months ago to improve my cardio for boxing. I started from about 500m without stopping to currently about 6km.

I run two or three times a week on consecutive days. Generally, a Tuesday, Wednesday and maybe Thursday. At the moment doing 6km on the Tuesday and 4km on Wednesday and maybe 2km on Thursday depending on how I feel. I try to increase the distance by 500m a week for each run.

The training is great, and I feel the benefit. The problem is that my calf pain, which is a combination of shin splints and actual calf muscle pain, is increasing exponentially. I don’t feel like I’m "getting used to it" even after 6 months. Is there anything someone can recommend to help? It’s getting so bad that I’m almost incapacitated the day after my long run and it’s getting worse. Generally by the next week I have recovered and the cycle repeats itself. I do a lot of weightlifting so DOMS is pretty common for me but this is another level.

For reference, I am 6ft 1, about 110kg and run on the road. I’m assuming a large part of the problem is my weight but I’m not really looking to lose any weight as I play rugby and while I’m not 10% body fat, I’m not severely overweight.

I feel like this is probably a common problem but looking for any and all advice.

Comment: Does the calf pain happen after the 6KM long run or the 2KM short run on Thursday?

Comment: A persistent, chronic injury is something you should have checked out by a qualified professional. Your primary care physician should be able to refer to you to a PT if the standard “take ten days off” advice they will probably start with doesn’t help.

Comment: As I stated in the question, this is general recovery issues. I'm fine by the next week. I was just wondering if there are tips to help.